# Artifacting with VirtualBox 4.3 seamless mode and Windows 8.1 guest

Tags: windows, virtualbox, xubuntu

Host OS is Xubuntu 12.10. When I try to run Windows 8.1 in VirtualBox 4.3, I'm getting some artifacting at the top of the screen (the orange is from the background image in the VM):

[image: Artifacting with Windows 8.1 VM]

Is there any way to eliminate this?

Comment: A workaround could be to have the same background on both OS.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I ended up doing.